# Spring batch MultiResourceItemReader - only used for combining files?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a Spring batch operation where I have sources `file1`, `file2` and `file3` to read from, and want to write to `fileA`, `fileB` and `fileC` like the following:

```
file1->fileA
file2->fileB
file3->fileC
```

When I look at an [example for `MultiResourceItemReader`](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-multiresourceitemreader-example/) it implies that the `[MultiResourceItemReader][2]` is useful for combining operations - but not pipelining parallel operations. ie the usage pattern of `MultiResourceItemReader` is for appending:

```
file1->file2->file3->fileC
```

If I want to read a sequence of files as separate operations- is `MultiResourceItemReader` still the way to go?

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiresourceparitioner, which is parallel and async, please refer spring batch sample programs [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-samples/src/main/resources/jobs/partitionFileJob.xml)

Answer (score 0):

MultiResourceItemReader:
`Reads items from multiple resources sequentially - resource list is given by setResources(Resource[]), the actual reading is delegated to setDelegate(ResourceAwareItemReaderItemStream).` 
So the job of MultiResourceItemReader is correctly done.
 The problem is after delegating reading to the actual reader.